# ionic cordova build android --prod --release Error :app:transformDexWithDexForRelease

Tags: android, ionic-framework, build

Yesterday I used this command and it was generated correctly, today I put sentry and now this command does not work,

is it because of the sing that applied yesterday?

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexWithDexForRelease'.
>     com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>     com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: Cannot merge new index
>     66590 into a non-jumbo instruction!
> - Try: 37 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 35 up-to-date Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 7s (node:13676) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
>   Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: FAILURE:
>   Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexWithDexForRelease'.
>     com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>     com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: Cannot merge new index
>     66590 into a non-jumbo instruction!
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 7s
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Goubun\Noediiler\neodiiler-ionic\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5) (node:13676)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:13676) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in the root of your project :

**cordova plugin add  https://github.com/jwall149/cordova-multidex --save**

It will install **cordova-multidex** and your build will work fine.